# Using TransferWise to pay for online shops

Tags: foreign-exchange, currency

I often use paypal to make the payment in online shops sites like ebay or amazon but the fee for currency conversion it makes the buy a little more expensive than i thought it should be.
Today i just stumbled with [this article](https://www.mobiletransaction.org/paypal-vs-transferwise/) in which basically says that transferwise don't charge on the exchange rates instead they charge a small fee, because the company uses its own accounts in the recipient’s country.

My question here is: i'm not sure how to set it up to use for buying for products with lower fee/total cost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So a few things to talk about re: your question:

### 1. Be wary of articles like that

There's a ton of them, and although they all look to be legitimately comparing pros and cons, make no mistake that they are collecting commissions. Often they collect commission or referral fees from both so it doesn't matter which you choose.

It doesn't mean that there isn't useful information to be had, but the "winner" in these types of articles tends to be the one that pays more at the moment. See also, all the credit card and airline miles blogs.

### 2. Transferwise Fees

I do use Transferwise, and in my experience they truly do not inflate the exchange rate (mid-market rate), and they tell you up front what their fees are. But that can also make it difficult to compare. If you're looking at other services the best way I've found is to get an estimate of the total transaction at the same time from both (the kind that says "you will send this much in currency A and the other party will receive this much in currency B" and compare the bottom line.

### 3. Online Shops / P2P

Transferwise is not really for paying online shops, and it's not the smooth kind of P2P that something like PayPal or Venmo or even Zelle is. You will need the full bank details of the person you're sending to and it takes time.

The newer Transferwise option they call the borderless account lets you hold balances in multiple currencies and get account details in a few. You can get a mastercard debit card that pulls from that balance and conversion happens automatically if you don't have any of the target currency. I believe you only pay the conversion fees (and if you have multiple source currencies they choose the cheapest), but there is a limit to ATM withdrawals.

Note that while you can *deposit* money into the account, you can't debit out of it easily (they're beta testing it as of this writing, only in EUR and GBP), except by using the debit card.

### 4. Consider directly using a credit or debit card

From what I've been able to tell, credit/debit cards *don't* inflate the conversion rate, and I think that's based on Visa/MC rules. Many banks *do* charge a foreign transaction fee on top (like 3%), so avoid those, but as long as you have one which has no FTF, you should get a great rate on par with Transferwise without paying a fee to convert.

When I first got the borderless account I did an experiment while I was in Canada and took out CAD $100 from an ATM from both my borderless account and my regular bank account, and indeed it was cheaper to use my regular bank account since there was no FTF. The rate was nearly identical.